# Logstash Elasticsearch Error : document_parsing_exception, object mapping for [] but found a concrete value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have a nested mapping and a config to parse JSON from a SQL database to elasticsearch with Logstash but I keep having "document_parsing_exception" error

I'm using jdbc input in logstash to index SQL database into Elasticsearch. I have JSON fields that I want to parse in Elasticsearch. I also have a mapping in Elasticsearch with nested fields as described in the tutorials I saw. If I remove the custom mapping from my index it works but I must have it in my project.

Here is the error message :

```
"error"=>{"type"=>"document_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"[1:93] object mapping for [myfield] tried to parse field [myfield] as object, but found a concrete value"}}}}
```

Here is how I configured a indexation

**Mapping ES :**

```
"myfield": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "lang": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
```

**Content of the matching field in the database**

```
[{"lang": "fr", "text": "text example"}]
```

I've tried two ways of parsing my field in Logstash : one with ruby (I think its a better way since I've got a lot of fields) and one with JSON

**Ruby :**

```
json_fields = [
    "myfield",
    [...]
]
json_fields.each do |field|
    if valid?(event.get(field))
    parsed_field = JSON.parse(event.get(field))
    if (parsed_field.is_a?(Hash) || parsed_field.is_a?(Array))
        event.set(field, parsed_field)
            else
        event.remove(field)
            end
    else
    event.remove(field)
    end
end
```

**JSON filter :**

```
json{
        source => "cdm_cours_7_7_rhythm"
        target => "cdm_cours_7_7_rhythm"
}
```

(And without any filter I've got the error message as if it didn't went through the filter)

Comment: The error clearly states that at least one value is NOT a JSON but simply a string. Can you make sure that whatever comes from your DB is always JSON?

Comment: In theory it is always JSON and for the post I took the matching doc the error was coming from (also it does that for all entries). The part I don't understand is that without a set mapping it behaves as JSON

Comment: If it's always JSON, then why do you need that convoluted ruby code? `json` filters should do the job easily

Comment: I've tried ruby because I have a lot of fields to parse to JSON (and I've set "security" just in case later). But JSON filters won't work either.

Comment: Can you try to use a `stdout` output instead of `elasticsearch` in order to see what is produced exactly?

Comment: With stdout I get that for the field 
```
"myfield" => "[{\"lang\": \"fr\", \"text\": \"Value\"}]",
```

Thanks I guess it's bc my fields are wrapped in quotes. I'm going to try finding a proper workaround

Comment: Right, it's a string value so you parsing logic doesn't work